# Directory Count and text return

Tags: vb.net, dialog, directory

I hope you can help me.

[image]

The image shows what really needs to do the program but the code does not work properly.

```html
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer) & ""
        If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then                
            TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim dir As Match = Regex.Match(str, "\\([^\\]+)\\")
            Dim count = TextBox1.Text.Count(Function(x) x = "\")                         
            TextBox2.Text = dir.Groups(count - 2).ToString      
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: _I went into a loop and can not get out of it_.  What loop? The image doesn't really describe what the program is doing, it could be doing anything, as you haven't named the form, the button or put labels next to any text boxes. What is your program trying to do? Does your code error when running and if so what's the error?

Comment: @Cal-cium. I updated the image. 

No error. In TextBox2 does not exit "desktop" but "user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your ask, the following code will give you the behavior you are looking for:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer)
    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim strFullPath As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        TextBox1.Text = Mid(strFullPath, InStrRev(strFullPath, "\") + 1)
        TextBox2.Text = strFullPath
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```